# evaluating json object returned from controller and attaching it to prepopulate attribute of tokeninput

Tags: json

I am using loopjs tokeninput in a View. In this scenario I need to prePopulate the control with AdminNames for a given Distributor.

Code Follows :

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("SearchCMSAdmins")", function (data) {

            var json=eval("("+data+")");    //doesnt work

            var json = {                    
                "users": [
                 eval("("+data+")")         //need help in this part
                ]
            }                
        });

        $("#DistributorCMSAdmin").tokenInput("@Url.Action("SearchWithName")", {
            theme: "facebook",                
            preventDuplicates: true,
            prePopulate: json.users

        });
```

There is successful return of json values to the below function. I need the json in the below format:

```
   var json = {
            "users": 
            [
               { "id": "1", "name": "USER1" },
               { "id": "2", "name": "USER2" },
               { "id": "3", "name": "USER3" }
            ]
          }
```

Comment: it is json object I am returning from my controller containing userid and username